# Error with If - else if statement with NAs R

Tags: r

I want to create a formula in R that **if** this or **else if** that to paste the appropriate values from the first two columns. For example:

```
 Fruit       Colour    Colour_group
 banana      yellow    yellow  
 banana      yellow
 pear        green     green
 pear        green
 pineapple   yellow    yellow
 pineapple   yellow
 apple       green     green
 apple       green                


green<-1
yellow<-1
for (i in 1:nrow(fruits){
   if (fruits$Colour_group[i] == "yellow"){
          yellow[i] <- paste(fruits$Fruit[i],fruits$Colour[i])
   } else if (fruits$Colour_group[i] == "green"){
          green[i] <- paste(fruits$Fruit[i],fruits$Colour[i])
   } else {
     next
   }}
```

I am trying to get only the unique values without NAs, but I get only the first value for yellow (banana yellow) and nothing for the green. Can you  please help me? Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?
Last, I have tried with and without NAs in the blanks in the Colour_group column. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? (use `dput`)  along with expected result

Comment: I want to get is character vector: "banana yellow" "pineapple yellow"  and no other values. I hope I am explaining it right..

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Give the expected result from ythe data you provided

Comment: I want to get two character vectors based on the colour group.There are duplicate and unique values in the first two columns (fruits and colour) but I need only the first instance. For example, yellow will contain only "banana yellow" "pineapple yellow", character green will contain only "pear green" "apple green". I don't to have the NAs from the Colour_group column. I should have explained it better. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just subset by the Colour Group and paste from there?

```
yellow <- fruits[fruits$Colour_group == 'yellow',]
green <- fruits[fruits$Colour_group == 'green',]
yellow_fruits <- paste(yellow$Fruit,yellow$Colour)
green_fruits <- paste(green$Fruit,green$Colour)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get a character vector with values in the first and fifth position and the rest are NAs.